how to set loading based on axios interceptor?


import axios from "axios";

const api = axios.create({ baseURL: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}` });

// request
api.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    if (token) {
      config.headers.Authorization = token;
    }
    // config.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    console.log(config);

    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log("error", error);

    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

// response
api.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    return response;
  },
  (error) => {
    /*      error handling       */
    // console.log(error);

    const originalRequest = error.config;

    console.log(originalRequest);

    // expired token
    if (error.response.status === 401) {
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }

    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

export default api;
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>



This is my middleware file. I need to set the loader globally.
But I don't know how to pass the data in function. ( outside the functional component )
And also I need to throw 401 error message.
Thank you...
